# Filtering in r with if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, filter

I want to filter a `data.frame` as follows:

mwe:

```
qdf= data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                month= rep(c(0,6,12),4),
                result = c(4,5,NA,5,6,7, 6,NA,6,4,NA,NA))
qdf
   id month result
1   1     0      4
2   1     6      5
3   1    12     NA
4   2     0      5
5   2     6      6
6   2    12      7
7   3     0      6
8   3     6     NA
9   3    12      6
10  4     0      4
11  4     6     NA
12  4    12     NA
```

I want to filter the data, grouped by `id`, to find every `id` that has a `result` at `month` 6 or 12 that isn't `NA`.

The result should be:

```
  id month result
1  1     0      4
2  1     6      5
3  1    12     NA
4  2     0      5
5  2     6      6
6  2    12      7
7  3     0      6
8  3     6     NA
9  3    12      6
```

Where rows for `id` == 4 are excluded as `result` is `NA` at both `month` 6 and 12.

I think I want to start by grouping by `id` but don't know where to go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset the values of result by the month you are interested and check for NA values

```
qdf %>% 
  filter(any(!is.na(result[month %in% c(6,12)])), .by=id)
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use `any(...)`, which given the conditions will return all rows (per `id`) where at least one row meets the condition, or it returns none of the rows if no rows match it.

```r
qdf %>%
  filter(any(month %in% c(6, 12) & !is.na(result)), .by = id)
#   id month result
# 1  1     0      4
# 2  1     6      5
# 3  1    12     NA
# 4  2     0      5
# 5  2     6      6
# 6  2    12      7
# 7  3     0      6
# 8  3     6     NA
# 9  3    12      6
```

This is just as direct in base R as well using `ave`:

```r
qdf[with(qdf, ave(month %in% c(6, 12) & !is.na(result), id, FUN = any)),]
```